# div not accepting class

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag with a class attribute in my .php file.
I also have two identical classes in my .css file the only difference being the names (.login-container & .login-fail-notificatin)
when I give the class attribute the ".login-fail-notification" class it works and does exactly what I need. however when I give it the other class: ".login-container" it doesnt do anything, it doesnt even show up in the browser inspect element.

I have no idea why it is doing this.
Also sorry I am still new to all this.
any help much appreciated :)

```html
<div class="login-container">
  ...
</div>
```

```css
.login-container
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
    left: 44.5%;
}

.login-fail-notification
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
    left: 44.5%;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working, I used `.login-container`, then `.login-fail-notification`, both shows the same result

Comment: if it isn't showing up in element inspector, it may be a problem with php if you use ssr.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code. It seems to be working perfectly.Probably you might have forgotten to link the css file with the html file.Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem with my ftp client not updating the file when I saved, feel like an idiot now haha.

Comment: @azxie in this case better deleted the question before you get more downvotes. In all the cases it will be closed and deleted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Ishaan _ It's a shame to start your SO experience with down votes - Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and find your way around _ Also the sections on Asking / Answering questons _ Some time on  research there will be a benefit later on ; ) >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: yeah I want to delete the question but am unable to now :(